# Most efficient way to find index of min difference for each element of two arrays

Tags: python-3.x

I have a two lists of three dimensional points; `a` containing 14894 points and `b` containing 1612 points.

For each point `a` I need to find the index of the closest point `b` in the XZ plane in the least time possible. This has to be done **only** with python core modules.

```
import time
from random import random

output = []

aL = 14894
aX = [round(random()*100, 2) for _ in range(aL)]
aZ = [round(random()*100, 2) for _ in range(aL)]

bL = 1612
bX = [round(random()*100, 2) for _ in range(aL)]
bZ = [round(random()*100, 2) for _ in range(aL)]


t0 = time.time()

for a in range(len(aX)):

    temp_diff = None
    temp_ind = None

    for b in range(len(bX)):

        diff = (aX[a] - bX[b]) ** 2 + (aZ[a] - bZ[b]) ** 2

        if not temp_diff or diff < temp_diff:
            temp_diff = diff
            temp_ind = b

    output.append(temp_ind)  

print("Elapsed time:", time.time() - t0)


>>> Elapsed time: 58.512130737304687
```

Comment: The distance between point `a` and point `b` should be `math.sqrt((aX[a] - bX[b]) ** 2 + (aZ[a] - bZ[b]) ** 2)`, so you should be looking to minimize `(aX[a] - bX[b]) ** 2 + (aZ[a] - bZ[b]) ** 2` rather than `abs(aX[a] - bX[b]) + abs(aZ[a] - bZ[b])`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, although your calculations are more precise they  increase time: `>>> Elapsed time: 67.977828979492187`

Comment: Efficiency means little if the output is incorrect. :-)

Comment: Ah you're right, I've corrected!